# PowerPoint Macro: Change font size based on colour of font

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to write a powerpoint macro where if my text colour is blue it will change the text size in shape. Not sure if it is possible? Appreciate your comments on the same

Comment: Do you want to test for a specific shade of blue (ie, one that you know the RGB values for) or for *any* shade of blue?  The former's simple, the latter is all but impossible.

Comment: I know the specific RGB value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub thing()
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim RGBColor As Long

' Change this as needed
RGBColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
    If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
        If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
            With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
                If .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                  .Font.Size = 12
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Or to change just the selected shape:

```
Sub ChangeFontByColor()
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim RGBColor As Long

' Change this as needed
RGBColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.Shaperange(1)    
    If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
        If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
            With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
                If .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                  .Font.Size = 12
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve thank you for above. However on trying the code there is no change happening. I also tried to alter it With Activewindow.Selection.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange and then RGB condition. As I have to change as per the shape I select. Very new to powerpoint vba

Comment: See the modified version; I've added a subroutine to affect just the currently selected shape (in NORMAL view).  You'll need to change this line to match the RGB color you're looking for: RGBColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Comment: Thank you Steve the code is working for other shapes. However the table I have pasted from excel to ppt it is not working on it. Any reason why so.

Comment: The code I wrote won't look "inside" SmartArt, Charts, PPT Tables or anything pasted from another application. Handling all of that would get wildly complicated.  But try ungrouping your Excel table repeatedly until you can select each bit of text within it.  The code will probably work then.